# Problem in the Big O notation

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

I have this expression $$ e^{\alpha(x,y)y} -1$$ where $\alpha(x,y)$ is a smoooth function of two variables and is bounded on $\mathbb{R^2}$.

1. As $y \rightarrow 0$, can I write
   $$ e^{\alpha(x,y)y} -1 = O\big(\alpha(x,y)y\big) \quad ?$$
2. Since $\alpha(x,y)y$ is bounded, can I simply write
   $$ e^{\alpha(x,y)y} -1 =O(y) \quad ?$$
3. If 2) is true, I can  conclude that in a neighborhood of $y=0$
   $$ \big| e^{\alpha(x,y)y} -1 \big| \leq A |y|, $$
   where $A$ is independent from both $x$ and $y$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have definition that $O(g),x \to x_0$ is set of functions $$\left\lbrace f: \exists C_f>0, \ \exists \delta>0, \forall x, 0< |x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow  |f(x)| \leqslant C_f |g(x)\right\rbrace$$.

In your case, taking as variable $y$,  and considering $g(y)=\alpha(x,y)y$ we have: if $\alpha$ is bounded, i.e. $\alpha(x,y) < A$, then $f \in O(g)\Rightarrow  f \in O(y)$, which gives your 2. and 3.

Comment: we can say that $\big| e^{\alpha(x,y)y}-1 \big| \leq C \big| \alpha(x,y)y \big|$, but does this $C$ depend or not from $x$? If not, why?

Comment: Conditions on $C$ comes from conditions on $\alpha$. As you wrote, if it is bounded, that means boundedness for both variables, correct? So here we obtain independence from $x$. And  independence from $y$ for $C$ we have based on $O$ definition.

Comment: Yes, $\alpha$ is bounded for both variables. But before using boundedness of $\alpha$, when we say that, by $O$ definition, $\big| e^{\alpha(x,y)y}-1 \big|=O\big(\alpha(x,y)y \big)$ implies that $ \big|e^{\alpha(x,y)y}-1 \big| \leq C \big|\alpha(x,y)y \big|$,  is  C  dependent or not from $x$?

Comment: Understand, I did not answer to your 1 point, so write it here: Taylor expansion for exponent gives $e^t=1+O(t), t \to 0$. So here we have estimation with constant independent from exponent variable $t$: $|e^t-1| \leqslant C|t|$. You put $t=\alpha(x,y)$, but this, imho, not affects constant.